# esp8266 WiFi Cannot Connect to a PHP Server

Tags: esp8266, wifi, web-server, code-review, web

I am using a magnetic float switch sensor to monitor water level in a tank. I am using a ESP8266 board.

I am trying to send the data collected by it to a php page in a host called "weris.link". I've checked the WiFi ssid and password for a myriad of times, yet somehow the connection to server still failed.

Did i commit a mistake ?

Here's my code :

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#define FLOAT_SENSOR  D2     // the number of the pushbutton pin
#define LED           D8      // the number of the LED pin

const char* server = "weris.link"; // alamat server
const char* ssid = "aBee"; // SSID router wifi
const char* password = "xxxxx"; // password wifi
const char* SensorID = "Water_Level_Kelompok_1.Unsrat"; // ID sensor

const char* count1= "Water Tank Full";
const char* count2= "Water Level Low";
const char* recommend1= "Turn Off Flow";
const char* recommend2= "Turn on Flow";

WiFiClient client;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(FLOAT_SENSOR, INPUT_PULLUP);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi Connected");
  }


void loop() 
{
  if(digitalRead(FLOAT_SENSOR) == LOW) 
  {
    // turn LED on:
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    Serial.println(count1);
  } 
  else 
  {
    // turn LED off:
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    Serial.println(count2);
  }
  // mulai Kirim data sensor
   if (client.connect(server,80 && LED == HIGH)) {
    Serial.print("Posting data...");
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);
    Serial.println("Tank Full: " + String(count1) + ", Tank Level Below Normal: " + String(count2));

// dengan GET /path file php penangkap data
client.println("GET /iot/terima.php?data1=" + String(count1) + "&data2=" + String(recommend1) + "&sid=" +SensorID+ " HTTP/1.1");
client.println("HOST: weris.link");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println();
client.stop();
Serial.println();
digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);
}

else if(client.connect(server,80 && LED == LOW)) {
  client.println("GET /iot/terima.php?data1=" + String(count2) + "&data2=" + String(recommend2) + "&sid=" +SensorID+ " HTTP/1.1");
  client.println("HOST: weris.link");
  client.println("Connection: close");
  client.println();
  client.stop();
  Serial.println();
  digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);
 } 
  else {
Serial.println("Koneksi ke server gagal");
 }
  delay(5000);
}
```

Below is the screen capture from the serial monitor

[image: Here is my picture]

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
if (client.connect(server,80 && LED == HIGH)) {
```

is definitely not going to do anything useful. Nor is this line:

```
else if(client.connect(server,80 && LED == LOW)) {
```

In both lines you're take the logical AND of the number 80 and the result of testing the LED.

Put the closing parenthesis in correct place:

```
if (client.connect(server,80) && LED == HIGH) {
```

and

```
else if(client.connect(server,80) && LED == LOW) {
```

Written this way you're still connecting twice if the LED is LOW. The code would be better written:

```
if (client.connect(server,80)) {
    if(LED == HIGH) {
      do stuff
    } else {
      do other stuff
    }
}
```

Even better would be to have the *do stuff* and *do other stuff* sections just set some variables and then write the code to talk to the web server once, using those variables. Having a single instance of the code will help avoid bugs in the future if you ever need to change it - the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle of programming.

Also, I hope you didn't just publish your wifi password here. If you did, you should change it.

Comment: `LED` is a pin number not a pin state.

Comment: good point! I'm sure that @Kenneth W. A. can take it as an exercise for the reader to correct that part of his code :)

Comment: Thank you very much, i really appreciate the help, restructured my code, it's working now